# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземплятор объекта

Tags: c#

Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземплятор объекта. Как исправить, и что это значит?

```
    namespace English_Learning_Application.Controller
{
    class LoginControl
    {
        TBL_USERTableAdapter TU = new TBL_USERTableAdapter();
        KeyGenerator KG = new KeyGenerator();

        public bool Check_Login(string username, string pass)
        {
            //string temp_password = TU.Get_Password(username).ToString();
            string decrypt_password = KG.EncryptString(pass);
            pass = decrypt_password;

            bool check = false;

            try
            {
                if (TU.GetUser(username, pass).ToString() != "")
                {
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                check = false;
            }
            return check;
        }
```

Ругается на: `if (TU.GetUser(username, pass).ToString() != "")`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `(username).ToString();` - вот эта строчка что делает?

Comment: @Igor, ругается на: if (TU.GetUser(username, pass).ToString() != "")

Comment: Я догадался. :)

Comment: @Igor, спасибо! :)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var u = TU.GetUser(username, pass);
if (u != null && u.ToString() != "")
{
   check = true;
}
```